# how to delete node children?

Tags: aem, jcr

before I write may sitemap.xml in some jcr folder `/var/myProject/sitemap`, I would like to delete the old sitemap.xml

```
Resource resource = resourceResolver.getResource("/var/myProject/sitemap");
sitemapNode = resource.adaptTo(Node.class);
sitemapNode.getNodes().remove();
```

`sitemapNode.getNodes().remove();` deliver the following exception:

```
*ERROR* [CM Event Dispatcher (Fire ConfigurationEvent: pid=MyClass] The start method has thrown an exception (java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException)
```

How to remove all children of the sitemapNode ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sitemapNode.getNodes();` returns a [NodeIterator](http://www.day.com/specs/jsr170/javadocs/jcr-2.0/javax/jcr/NodeIterator.html). The `remove()` method available in that is the one inherited from [Iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html).

Quoting the docs `remove()`

> Removes from the underlying collection the last element returned by
>   this iterator (optional operation)

When you try to remove from an unmodifiable collection, it gives the `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Either remove the `sitemapNode` using `sitemapNode.remove()` and recreate it (this would remove all its children along with the node), or iterate through each child and then call the remove() method individually. This would invoke the Node's `remove()` method inherited from [javax.jcr.Item](http://www.day.com/specs/jsr170/javadocs/jcr-2.0/javax/jcr/Item.html#remove()).